# Cannot parse json to List of custom objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to parse my json response that look like this one:

```
{
"response":
    {
    "status":"ok",
    "userTier":"developer",
    "total":12075,
    "startIndex":1,
    "pageSize":10,
    "currentPage":1,
    "pages":1208,
    "orderBy":"relevance",
    "results":[
        {
        "type":"article",
        "sectionId":"world",
        "webTitle":"Putin-themed cafe opens in Siberia",
        "webPublicationDate":"2016-04-13T14:56:42Z",
        "id":"world/2016/apr/13/vladimir-putin-themed-cafe-opens-in-siberia",
        "webUrl":"http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/apr/13/vladimir-putin-themed-cafe-opens-in-siberia",
        "apiUrl":"http://content.guardianapis.com/world/2016/apr/13/vladimir-putin-themed-cafe-opens-in-siberia",
        "sectionName":"World news"
        },
        {
        "type":"article",
        "sectionId":"world",
        "webTitle":"Spain issues arrest warrants for Russian officials close to Putin",
        "webPublicationDate":"2016-05-04T16:59:27Z",
        "id":"world/2016/may/04/spain-issues-arrest-warrants-for-russian-officials-close-to-putin",
        "webUrl":"http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/may/04/spain-issues-arrest-warrants-for-russian-officials-close-to-putin",
        "apiUrl":"http://content.guardianapis.com/world/2016/may/04/spain-issues-arrest-warrants-for-russian-officials-close-to-putin",
        "sectionName":"World news"
        }
```

I created my classes using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) (Insert this string: http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=putin&api-key=6392a258-3c53-4e76-87ec-e9092356fa74)
But I had the follow error when I tried to parse it:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewsModel.RootObject>>(data);
```

Actually I got my data in this way:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=putin&api-key=6392a258-3c53-4e76-87ec-e9092356fa74");
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader readStream = null;

   if (response.CharacterSet == "")
       readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
   else
       readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

       string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       StringReader reader = new StringReader(data);

// parse here
}
```

> Something bad with json parsing. Message: Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[sample.NewsModel+RootObject]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'response', line 1, position
>   12.Something bad with json parsing. Message: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[sample.NewsModel+RootObject]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'response', line 1, position
>   12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to deserialize the response as an array (response would be `[...]`) instead of a single object (response, as shown, is `{...}`). Change your code to:

`var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsModel.RootObject>(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
using System.Net;

string requestUrl = String.Format("http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=putin&api-key=6392a258-3c53-4e76-87ec-e9092356fa74");
string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(requestUrl);

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json.ToString());
object result = dict["results"];

foreach (object items in result as System.Collections.ArrayList)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> item = (Dictionary<string, object>)items;
    string type = item["type"];
    string sectionId = item["sectionId"];
    ...
    ...
    ...
    //or
    //foreach(object item in items) { }
}
```